# Consecutive struct bitfields not behaving as expected. Doesn't appear to be a padding issue

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-fields, ntp

I'm experimenting with the SNTP protocol. While attempting to modify the message struct I ran into issue I cannot explain.  Despite the fact that the first 32-bit word contains 6 fields, the struct I found as an example concatenated the first 3 fields (8-bits).  The code works fine like this, but I would prefer to pack the message with bitfields, to avoid bitwise logic every time I pack the message.

```
                  1                   2                   3
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
  |LI | VN  |Mode |    Stratum    |     Poll      |   Precision   |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Here is what is happening.  I have a uint8_t field called li_vn_mode, and I want to pack the values of LI=0, VN=3, Mode=3.

This works

```
li_vn_mode = 0x1b;
```

So does this

```
li_vn_mode = (0 | 3 << 3 | 3);
```

However, replacing this field in the struct with three bitfield entries like this, and trying to indivitually pack the decimals does not work.

```
uint8_t li    :2;
uint8_t vn    :3;
uint8_t mode  :3;
```

What is the difference?  When I check the size of these fields within a struct it appears to be 1 byte, so I do not believe padding is being added.

Comment: struct layout for bit fields is dependent on the compiler being used. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Variable-Attributes.html) for related gcc parameters. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Good information.  I'm using the clang compiler.  It seems that the primary difference is they way zero length fields are treated.